# Liquibase: Convert createTable changeSet entry to DDL SQL statement

Tags: sql, jdbc, ddl, liquibase

I'd like to use JDBC to create tables in a database agnostic way. I'm pretty sure that Liquibase has solved this problem since it can take a generic `createTable` XML `changeSet` element and convert it into a database specific SQL DDL statement.

Can someone please tell me which liquibase classes / utililities are involved in converting a generic `createTable changeSet` into a database specific `create table` SQL script?. Sample usage (ie a test case) would be great.

Please note that I do not wish to invoke the entire liquibase pipeline. In particular I do NOT want the `databasechangelog` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend reading the [liquibase unit tests](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/liquibase-parent-3.0.2/liquibase-core/src/test/java/liquibase/change/core/CreateTableChangeTest.java).

Comment: Thanks v. much. It looks like ```SqlStatement[] statements = change.generateStatements(new MockDatabase());``` is where the SQL is generated.